# Can I get a working jsTree 3.0 example in Asp.NET MVC 4 with async loading of nodes?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, lazy-loading, jstree

I have been struggling for the last three days with jsTree control and can't make it work behind the root node. Can you please provide me with a full working example, nodes should be fetched in backend (ASP.NET MVC C#) and loaded dynamically (they are files/folders on local disk) after user selects some node?

Answer (score 1):

Open a new MVC 4 project in VS and include jsTree (the one with the image) from nuget.

It will create a controller and two views. These are working examples that you can look at and see how things work. Note: I had to change the url in the AJAXDemo from "/jsTree3/GetJsTree3Data" to "/[MyProjectName]/jsTree3/GetJsTree3Data"

This is the best example and you can then use this knowledge in your other projects.